# How to close dropdown by clicking any where in HTML page

Tags: jquery

```
**Script**
$('.select ul li.option').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggle().removeClass('darr');
    $(this).addClass('darr');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WFTvq/2/

Hi frnds here the dropdown is working but i need if i click any where in the html apart from dropdown also the drop down should close. can any one suggest solution.